Refining a union of tuples
I'm trying to refine a type that is one or the other of two tuples, but I can't get TS to cooperate.
declare const foo: [string, string] | [number, number];
declare function isNumber(x: unknown): x is number;

if (isNumber(foo[0])) {
  foo; // not refined
}

Is this possible?  ts playground

Your playground is flawed.  The isNumber function only asserts that its argument is a number.  That's it.  Nothing is known about either the size of the tuple or about the type of the second element.  You need an isNumericTuple() function, not an isNumber function.

@JoséRamírez it's definitely provable that if one element of the tuple is a number, the other cannot be a string. Not much different from discriminated unions - we can examine one property and TS can conclude something about another we've not examined. If you still think the example is flawed, you can explain the logic by which you can have a mixed tuple in this setup. However, TS simply doesn't do this check here. There are a lot of logically provable things that TS does not try to prove. The problem is not in the logic, it's a TS limitation.

There is a feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#42384 to narrow parent objects when narrowing properties. Currently TypeScript only filters discriminated unions when you check its discriminant property. But although the type [number, number] | [string, string] is a union, it's not considered a discriminated union, since neither number nor string are valid discriminants. Discriminant property types need to have literal types like "stringLiteral" or 123. The number and string types are just too wide.
Until and unless microsoft/TypeScript#42384 is implemented, you'll need to work around it. You could, if you want, write your own custom type guard function that takes an object of union type, a key name, and a type guard for the property at that key, and uses those to discriminate the union:
// discriminate union T to members with a value of type V at key K
function hasPropOfType<T, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]>(
    obj: T, k: K, guard: (x: T[K]) => x is V): obj is Extract<T, Record<K, V>> {
    return guard(obj[k])
}

And then you can write hasPropOfType(foo, 0, isNumber) in place of isNumber(foo[0]):
if (hasPropOfType(foo, 0, isNumber)) {
    foo;
    //^? const foo: [number, number]
    foo[1].toFixed()
} else {
    foo;
    //^? const foo: [string, string]
    foo[1].toUpperCase()
}

Playground link to code

TS doesn't track correlation between tuple members, I would suggest some generic approach:
Playground
type DoubleTuple<T> = [T, T];
declare const foo: DoubleTuple<number> | DoubleTuple<string>;
type Types = {string: string, number: number};
declare function isDoubleTupleOfType<T extends keyof Types>(x: DoubleTuple<any>, type: T): x is DoubleTuple<Types[T]>;

if (isDoubleTupleOfType(foo, 'number')) {
  foo; 
  //^?
  const n = foo[0];
  //    ^?
}

